# SQL asking for a password I didn't set

Tags: psql

Im learning psql/sql

The problem i am having is the program keeps asking for the password for User `testuser2`, but I didn't set a password for this User, so I don't know what the password could be. I've tried using the password for User `postgress` but it still wouldn't work.

Code

```
Server [localhost]:
Database [postgres]:
Port [5432]:
Username [postgres]:
Password for user postgres:
psql (14.2)
WARNING: Console code page (850) differs from Windows code page (1252)
         8-bit characters might not work correctly. See psql reference
         page "Notes for Windows users" for details.
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# \l
                                                    List of databases
     Name     |   Owner   | Encoding |           Collate           |            Ctype            |   Access privileges
--------------+-----------+----------+-----------------------------+-----------------------------+-----------------------
 postgres     | postgres  | UTF8     | English_United Kingdom.1252 | English_United Kingdom.1252 |
 room_booking | cs_staff  | UTF8     | English_United Kingdom.1252 | English_United Kingdom.1252 |
 template0    | postgres  | UTF8     | English_United Kingdom.1252 | English_United Kingdom.1252 | =c/postgres          +
              |           |          |                             |                             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 template1    | postgres  | UTF8     | English_United Kingdom.1252 | English_United Kingdom.1252 | =c/postgres          +
              |           |          |                             |                             | postgres=CTc/postgres
 todolist2    | testuser2 | UTF8     | English_United Kingdom.1252 | English_United Kingdom.1252 |
(5 rows)


postgres=# todolist2 testuser2
postgres-# \c todolist2 testuser2
Password for user testuser2:
connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "testuser2"
Previous connection kept
postgres-#
```

Comment: Someone created a user `testuser2` and made it the owner of the database `todolist2`. If you didn't do that, then ask whoever is responsible for setting up that Postgres instance

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I could only assume it was me, as i'm following a tutorial on my personal laptop.

Comment: As you seem to know the password of the superuser (`postgres`)  you can easily set a new password for `testuser2` using the `\password` command in `psql`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name im new to SQL and I dont know how to do that yet

Comment: As I wrote: use the `\password`  command in `psql` to change the password. See [the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html) for details